# Recomendations on stack config

Tags: sql, ignite, apache-calcite

Experiencing performance problems on writing data to Ignite stack.
Doing next queries

```
MERGE INTO ... VALUES ((...)...) ON () WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ... WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ... VALUES (...)
```

with 1-2 values it takes about 100-150ms in average (and growing to 600-700ms) when expected to be under 10ms. Average execution time constantly grows.

**Additional details**:
Connecting as thin jdbc client.
Use Calcite as query engine.
Ingite stack has 40 data nodes.
Stack sync is done with zookeeper.
Connecting using r53 address.
The table is partitioned with 1 backup.
Query execution time are from SYS.SQL_QUERY_HISTORY

**The questions here are**:
why this query takes so much time?
and what are recomendations for stack to save dozens of millions of rows (amount of nodes, amount of CPUs, heap size...)?

Tried to turn off persistance - that didn't change exectuion time
Tried to use partitionAwareness=true - that didn't change exectuion time

Table creation script

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS status (
  r_id VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  a_id VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  con_e BIGINT,
  con_s VARCHAR(30),
  a_e BIGINT,
  a_s VARCHAR(30),
  a_con_st VARCHAR(30),
  PRIMARY KEY (r_id, a_id)
) WITH "template=partitioned,backups=1,affinity_key=r_id";
```

Example of full MERGE

```
MERGE INTO status dst USING 
(VALUES
 (CAST('r1' AS VARCHAR),CAST('a1' AS VARCHAR),1464366133047,'c','n'),
 (CAST('r20' AS VARCHAR),CAST('a2' AS VARCHAR),1465481887428,'c','n')
) src(r_id,a_id,con_e,con_s,a_con_st) 
ON (dst.r_id = src.r_id AND dst.a_id = src.a_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
 UPDATE SET 
 con_s=(CASE WHEN (dst.con_e < src.con_e OR dst.con_e IS NULL) THEN src.con_s ELSE dst.con_s END),
 con_e=(CASE WHEN (dst.con_e < src.con_e OR dst.con_e IS NULL) THEN src.con_e ELSE dst.con_e END)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT
 (r_id,a_id,con_e,con_s,a_con_st) VALUES(src.r_id,src.a_id,src.con_e,src.con_s,src.a_con_st);
```

Comment: Try this option too https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/perf-and-troubleshooting/sql-tuning#skip-reducer-on-update. It will remove additional hop during updating

Comment: skipReducerOnUpdate didn't help, execution time is about the same

Comment: Just in case, could you please add CREATE TABLE command and full MERGE command? Also I see the tag for apache-calcite. Are you testing Apache Ignite 3.0? As I know 2.X uses H2 engine.

Comment: Using ignite 2.15.0 with Calcite as per https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/SQL/sql-calcite version is also 2.15.0 from libs.

Comment: Updated with queries

Comment: Sorry, I tried to clarify and looks like all optimization performance suggestions from the current documentation is related to H2 engine. Your case looks strange. Unfortunatly I didn't test the new engine yet. However, I suggest you to write an email to the deleloper's mail lists (https://calcite.apache.org/community/#mailing-lists or dev@ignite.apache.org).  Because issue can be related to saving data into the cache, try the second one first.